# AWS EC2 Instance suddendly running very slow after importing database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance and I've been using it to play with a database backup (importing it with a PHP script, then changing the parameters and importing it again, and so on).

Yesterday, my import script was taking ~10 minutes.
Today, it's taking ~10 hours.

What's the problem and how can I solve it?
I checked with top command on the terminal and the CPU usage is quite low, and I checked the monitoring of my EC2 instance and I have full CPU credits balance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was not the CPU credits, but rather the EBS I/O Burst Credits.

I found the answer at this link:

https://aws.amazon.com/it/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-slow-cpu-not-high/

> ```
> Resolution
> Check I/O burst credit balance
> Open the Amazon EC2 console.
> In the navigation pane, choose Instances, and then select the instance.
> On the Description tab, choose the Root device link, and then choose the EBS ID link.
> Choose the Monitoring tab for the EBS volume, and then find the Burst Balance metric
> ```

If your burst balance Is 0%, then you need to wait for it to go back up or provision a EBS device with different parameters to support higher sustained I/O loads.